# How to have implementation-agnostic methods while maintaing performance in OOP?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

This is tagged as C++ because that's what I'm working in, but the question is about OOP in general. I'm making a chess engine program and I have classes `Board` and `Move`. Board contains the representation data of the chessboard with all it's pieces and also implements `std::vector<Move> AvailableMoves()` which returns a list of playable moves from the current position. It also implements `void PlayMove(Move x)` which plays the move on the board.

`Move` just contains information about a chess move (ex. black moves knight from d3 to c2) that is stored in some way. I have not yet decided which methods it implements because that is part of my question.

Since this is a chess engine, it is supposed to be high-performance. That means that the internal implementation of `Move` and `Board` is very important. For example, if we represent both of them with a bitmask, then we can use some [bit-manipulation trickery](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Bitboards) to make `PlayMove()` very fast. However, if `Move` is internally represented as a string (ex. "Qd4", meaning queen to d4) then the bitmask optimization is no longer possible in the `PlayMove()` method. And this leads me to my dilemma:

If I want to use the bitmask optimization, then I have to make the implementation of `PlayMove()` and `Move` fixed, and not let it change, which is in direct violation of the principles of implementations-agnostic design. Also it generally seems like a bad idea if I ever want to change the implementation.

On the other hand, if I want to make the methods implementation-agnostic, then I won't be able to reap the performance benefits of having a bitmask implementation, because that implementation is no longer guaranteed to be made with bitmasks.

Is there a method to have it both ways? To both have an implementation-agnostic `Move` class, but also be able to reap the performance benefits of having a specific implementation of `Move`?

Comment: your approach of using strings to represent moves is in contrast to wanting high-performance. You need to parse the string to know which tile to move where. Also it is not clear from what you wrote why this prevents to use bitmask tricks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why strings are an example of low-preformance in my question. What prevents the use of bitmasks is not the strings, but rather the implementation-agnostic design. The implementation of `Move` must be **gurnateed** to be a bitmask if `PlayMove()` wants to use it as a bitmask. But then we don't have implementation-agnostic design.

Comment: It's a contradiction to both want to be implementation-agnostic (i.e. to allow any implementation) and also want to guarantee good performance by only allowing a particular implementation.  If you're going to allow *any* implementation, then you're going to have to allow low-performance implementations.  And that's not necessarily a bad thing; nobody forces you to *use* the low-performance implementation in situations where you need good efficiency.  (You could make your bitmask operations part of the high-efficiency implementation; the low-performance one can do whatever it wants)

Comment: this is just typical trade-off between fast code and nice-looking/easy-to-read code. The standard advice is to have good interfaces, practice good design re:data hiding etc., and do your implementation the clean/easy-to-read way, then when and if performance becomes a problem re-implement problem areas for performance. if the design is good you should only need to touch implementations not interfaces.